# I can't run Scada-Lts, WebappClassLoaderBase and ViewGraphicLoader classes errors

Tags: java, scada

When I tried to run Scada-Lts on Tomcat 8.0.24 I got the following error:

```
23-Sep-2016 11:03:27.228 INFO [Timer-0] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [java.util.ListIterator]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [java.util.ListIterator]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1335)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1321)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1203)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1164)
at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.evict(GenericObjectPool.java:981)
at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool$Evictor.run(GenericObjectPool.java:1112)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

and a lots of error like:

```
WARN  2016-09-23 11:03:17,125 (com.serotonin.mango.view.ViewGraphicLoader.loadViewGraphics:58) - Failed to load image set at C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\GitHubProjects\Scada-LTS\out\artifacts\scadabr_1_1_0_RC_war_exploded\graphics\Weather 
java.lang.Exception: Unable to derive image dimensions
```

Somebody knows why I got those errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please run [Scada-LTS](https://github.com/sdtabilit/Scada-LTS/tree/develop-sdtabilit) on tomcat7.

Scada-LTS have not been migrated to tomcat8 ([migrating](https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-8.html))

I mean the problem is paths in app Scada-LTS.